# How to count the all possible orders of the subgroups of $\Bbb Z_{19}^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know the all possible orders of the subgroups of $\Bbb Z_{19}^*$ is $1,~2,~3,~6,~9,~18$ (by brutal force). But how can I count it in a smart way? Not so tedious.. Question 2: If the question is modified as "does the group exist a subgroup of order $6$?" How can I check this?

(I haven't learnt Sylow Theorem, Cauchy Theorem, etc. So does there exist a more simpler way?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The no. of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{19}^*$ is 18. So, from Lagrange's theorem, the possible order of the group are divisors of 18, i.e. 1,2,3,6,9,18 (as suggested by you).

But coming to your question,"does the group exist a subgroup of order 6?", as we know converse of Lagrange's theorem is not true. Hence, you have to check that explicitly.

But since here the group is cyclic: a cyclic group of order $n$ always has one subgroup of each order that divides $n$.
So $\mathbb{Z}_{19}^*$ has one subgroup for each divisor of $18$. And $6$ is a divisor of $18$.

Comment: I should compute $2^1,2^2,2^3,2^4,\cdots$ (mod $19$) till seeing the cyclic fashion, and select something not in this very set, and keep doing the same thing?

Comment: Just getting an $a \in$  $\mathbb{Z}_{19}^*$ s.t. $a^6\equiv 1$ (mod 19) would do your work. And $a^i\neq1$ for $1\le i\le5$.

Comment: Here $a=7$ would do the trick for you. As $7^6\equiv 1 $(mod 19).

Comment: I see. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

The multiplicative group of non-zero elements modulo a prime $p$ is always cyclic of order $p-1$. And a cyclic group of order $n$ always has exactly one subgroup of each order that divides $n$.

In your case, $p-1=18$, so $\Bbb Z_{19}^*$ has one subgroup for each divisor of $18$. And $6$ is a divisor of $18$.

Comment: Is "The multiplicative group of non-zero elements modulo a prime p is always cyclic" followed from an advanced theorem that multiplicative subgroup of a finite field is cyclic?

Comment: @Shara It's not that advanced. Basically, if the group were not cyclic, then there would be too many elements of lower orders, so the polynomial $x^d-1$ would have more than $d$ roots for some $d$'s. That can't be in a field.

Comment: @s1mple Arthur is correct.  A cyclic group has a _unique_ subgroup of each order dividing the order of the group.

Comment: @s1mple if $d|n$, there will be $\varphi(d)$ elements of order $d$, but, they all generate the same subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

$(\mathbb{Z}_{19}^{*},×)$ is cyclic group of order $18$.And
Note that, for any finite cyclic group $G$ of order $n$, for any $d|n$,
$G$ has unique subgroup of order $d$ and $\phi(n/d)$ elements of order $d$.

Claim: $(\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*},×)$ is cyclic group of order $p-1$.

Proof:
It is clearly abelian.

Let, $l=\text{lcm}(\text{ord}(1),\text{ord}(2),\cdots,\text{ord}(p-1))$

Then we have, $x^l=1$ for any$x \in \Bbb Z_p ^*$, because $\text{ord}{x} | l$

Also note that, $Q(X)=X^l-1$ can be seen as polynomial in $\mathbb Z_p ^* [X]$

Note that , $Q(X)$ has $p-1$ distinct roots namely, $\{1,2,...,p-1\}$.
Since $Q(X)$ is polynomial over field $\Bbb Z_p ^*$,

So we have $\text{deg}(Q(X))=l \geq p-1$....(#1)

(This happens because $\Bbb Z_p ^* [X]$ is Euclidean Domain, similar to $\mathbb R[X]$ where we have euclidean algorithm.)

Note that in abelian group ,order of products of elements is equal to LCM of their orders. (....(#2))

So from (#1) and (#2),

There must exist element $g$ in $\mathbb Z_p ^* $ having order $p-1$.